# Scheduled Apex, changed CreatedDate with json.deserialize, but still not working?

Tags: apex, scheduled

I have a strange problem. Following Class:

```
global class leadToBoerseAfter24H implements Schedulable{
     // Execute method
        global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
            // Code to be executed when the schedule class wakes up
            for(List<Lead> leads:[SELECT FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone, PostalCode, City, Street, Email, CreatedDate FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate < YESTERDAY AND Email != null AND Status = 'Offen' AND (Lead_Status__c = null OR Lead_Status__c = 'Telefonisch nicht erreicht') AND (LeadSource = 'FWS Lead' OR LeadSource = 'AdressButler' OR LeadSource = 'WH Landingpage')]){
                 List<lb_Leads__c> nL = new List<lb_Leads__c>();
                for(Lead l : leads){
                   lb_Leads__c newL = new lb_Leads__c();
                   newL.Vorname__c = l.FirstName;
                   newL.Nachname__c = l.LastName;
                   newL.Telefon__c = l.Phone;
                   newL.Erstellt_datum__c = date.today();
                   newL.Auktionsstart__c = date.today();
                   newL.Anfangspreis__c = 120;
                   newL.Status__c = 'active';
                   newL.Stadt__c = l.City;
                   if(l.PostalCode != null)
                       newL.PLZ__c = l.PostalCode;
                   else
                       newL.PLZ__c = 'Keine Angabe';
                   newL.Stra_e__c = l.Street;
                   newL.Email__c = l.Email;
                   newL.Mobiltelefon__c = l.MobilePhone;
                   newL.Beschreibung__c = 'Pflegeimmobilie als Kapitalanlage';
                   nL.add(newL);
                }
                if(!nL.isEmpty()){
                    insert nL;
                    delete leads;
                }
            }
       }
     }
```

Following testclass:

```
@istest
class TestLeadToBoerse {

   static testmethod void test() {
     Lead l = (Lead) Json.deserialize('{"Company":"foo", "LastName":"bar",' + 
                                   '"Email":"foo@bar.com",' +
                                   '"CreatedDate": "2015-04-04T17:54:26.000+0000",'  +
                                         '"Status": "Offen", ' +
                                       '"LeadSource": "WH Landingpage",' +
                                         '"Lead_Status__c": "Telefonisch nicht erreicht",' +
                                           '"PostalCode": "33333", ' +
                                           '"FirstName": "Test",' +
                                          '"Gesch_ftsbeziehung__c": "Interessent",' +
                                           '"Maklerbetreuer_Wirtschaftshaus__c" : "Lars Wagner"}',
                                         Lead.class);
   insert l;
   String lName = l.FirstName;
      System.assertEquals(lName,
         [SELECT id, FirstName FROM Lead WHERE id = :l.id].FirstName);
   Test.startTest();


      // Schedule the test job
      String jobId = System.schedule('testBasicScheduledApex',
      '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2015', 
         new LeadToBoerseAfter24H());

      // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
      CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, 
         NextFireTime
         FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];

      // Verify the expressions are the same
      System.assertEquals('0 0 0 3 9 ? 2015', 
         ct.CronExpression);

      // Verify the job has not run
      System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);

      // Verify the next time the job will run
      System.assertEquals('2015-09-03 00:00:00', 
         String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));

   Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

When I change the "WHERE CreatedDate < YESTERDAY" to "WHERE CreatedDate > YESTERDAY" it works flawlessly.

I debugged the l.CreatedDate after insertion and it logged the date I inserted in the json.deserialize. 
Am I missing something? Didn't I schedule to class to be executed on September 2015? So why is the CreatedDate > YESTERDAY and not the other way around?

Comment: You entered the date 4th April 2015 which is today.. which is obviously greater than Yesterday. Try with Created Date 2nd April 2015, your above code should work.

Comment: It's 4th of may :P

Comment: Oops! The weekend hangover is still there! Let me get a cup of coffee! ha ha!

Comment: Haha no Problem! I seriously don't get what's wrong with my code... It seems that the System.schedule doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inserted the CreatedDate, unless you have specifically asked Salesforce to enable editing of audit fields, which they will usually only do for short period of time (usually, to support a data migration project).  Are you sure your date is getting inserted?  You might want to add a try/catch around your lead insert just to make sure it is working correctly.  And for testing in this scenario, I frequently will make the SOQL a string so I can modify it for the test class, and I will execute the method in the scheduled class myself, to control how it is working.

Comment: I am 100% sure that it is working, and if you look through the web, the json.deserialize is a workaround to insert records with a custom CreatedDate. But yes, I tested it via: System.AssertEquals([select blabla], l.LastName) and System.debug(l.CreatedDate). Also, if the lead wouldn't be inserted, the test with CreatedDate > YESTERDAY would also result in low code coverage, but it is working just fine